# Python3.6 can't install latest version of yoyo-migrations

Tags: python

I want to install the latest version of yoyo-migrations module.

Based on https://pypi.org/project/yoyo-migrations/ the latest version is 5.1.0 and when I try to install it using `pip install yoyo-migrations` it installs the v5.0.5 and when using this command `pip install yoyo-migrations==5.1.0` it gives me this error.

> Collecting yoyo-migrations==5.1.0   Could not find a version that
>   satisfies the requirement yoyo-migrations==5.1.0 (from versions: 1, 2,
>   3, 4, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.2.0, 4.2.1,
>   4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.2.5, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5) No matching distribution found for yoyo-migrations==5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the files for that version [here](https://pypi.org/project/yoyo-migrations/5.1.0/#files) you will see that the only available file for that version is

> yoyo_migrations-5.1.0-py2-none-any.whl (42.1 kB)

The `py2` part indicates that this wheel is only good for python2, and not your version of python3, so `pip` is correct when it tells you that it can't find a suitable version. However, the version you're trying to download is only a few hours old, perhaps there will be additional files there soon.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can install the develop version.

```
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/ollyc/yoyo#egg=yoyo-migrations
```